# data gridview binding error coming in wpf application

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

i am beginner of WPF Application,,just now i started one small application in WPF allplication

in that i have a grid view ..while loading the page i want to populate some data to grid view..so i given code in my form load event like this:

```
Dim adapter As SqlDataAdapter
Dim dt1 As DataTabl
Private Sub Window_Loaded(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Loaded
  Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=SUPPORT2\SUPPORT2;Initial Catalog=Registry;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;password=solutions")
        con.Open()
        Dim cd As SqlCommandBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(adapter)
        adapter = New SqlDataAdapter("select c.cid,c.CompanyName,d.dtId,d.dtName as Department,d.dtPhone as Phone,d.dtEmail as Email from CompanyMaster_tbl c join  DepartmentMaster_tbl d on c.Cid=d.cId order by cid", con)
        dt1 = New DataTable
        adapter.Fill(dt1) 'Filling dt with the information from the DB
        DataGrid1.ItemsSource = dt1
```

while running the code i am getting error in this line:**DataGrid1.ItemsSource = dt1**
Error:
*Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataTable' to type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'*.
  please Gide  me how to write code in WPF applicatio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
DataGrid1.ItemsSource = dt1.DefaultView;
```

DefaultView is of type `DataView` which implements `IEnumerable`.

Here is a full example I used for testing, it is C# code, I hope you don't mind:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Col1 - int", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("Col2 - string", typeof(string));

table.Rows.Add(new object[] {1, "Smith"});
table.Rows.Add(new object[] {2, "John"});

grid.ItemsSource = table.DefaultView;
```

Here is the DataGrid declaration in XAML:

```
<DataGrid Name="grid" />
```

Comment: yes sir ,,this correct,not getting any error..but my datagrid not showing anything.i have to give any more code? database have some value

Comment: @user3106114 Hmm, this is very strange. You are using WPF's DataGrid and you are sure there is data in dt1? This works for me, try the code I added to the answer above. It is C# code, if that is a problem I can probably convert it to VB.

Comment: sir the same vb.net code working fine for my vb.net application..then why that is not working in WPF application

Comment: i have to do anything with WPF Datagrid

Comment: @user3106114 I really don't know how to help you, unless I have some more information. Like I said the code above works for me. Did you try it my example?

Comment: i am not familiar with C# application..so i haven't tried that

Comment: sir my self i found answer..i make it my data grid view AutoGenerateColumns="True"